# What are new features in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

Can some one help me to tell most important features that are included in angular 8.

Comment: Have you checked [here](https://angular.io/guide/releases) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Hello @anvesh https://blog.angular.io/tagged/release-notes

Comment: Also https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4

Comment: You can find detailed major changesets and also something useful here, 
https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4 AND
https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 1):

Angular7 is out, as well, angular releases a new version within 6 months.
Ivy Renderer is not out yet (93.4% completed) once its out, it's gonna reduce bundle sizes a lot.

A couple of changes in angular 6:
1. ng add is a new command in Angular-cli that helps you install and download new packages in your angular apps. It works the same as npm, but it doesn’t replace it.

2.Declaring the providers inside the service itself

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
```

3. Use ng-template instead of the template directive
4. Lots of work have been done on angular material.
5. Rxjs updated to v6, (changed the way operators were imported and used) (reduces import cost).

Hope this helps